# R - dplyr Summarize and Retain Other Columns

Tags: r, dplyr, summarize

I am grouping data and then summarizing it, but would also like to retain another column. I do not need to do any evaluations of that column's content as it will always be the same as the group_by column. I can add it to the group_by statement but that does not seem "right". I want to retain `State.Full.Name` after grouping by `State`. Thanks

```
TDAAtest <- data.frame(State=sample(state.abb,1000,replace=TRUE))
TDAAtest$State.Full.Name <- state.name[match(TDAAtest$State,state.abb)]


TDAA.states <- TDAAtest %>%
  filter(!is.na(State)) %>%
  group_by(State) %>%
  summarize(n=n()) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  arrange(State)
```

Comment: Which column you want to `summarise`?  Based on the code, you are doing it by both the columns

Comment: It's probably the best just grouping by both. The alternative is `summarize(State.Full.Name = unique(State.Full.Name), n=n())`, which is less concise.

Comment: @akrun I clarified. I had left in my not so "right" approach.

Comment: Also, `count(...)` is equivalent to `group_by(...) %>% summarise(n = n())`

Answer (score 45):

Perhaps we need

```
TDAAtest %>% 
     filter(!is.na(State)) %>%
     group_by(State) %>% 
     summarise(State.Full.Name = first(State.Full.Name), n = n())
```

---

Or use `mutate` to create the column and then do the `distinct`

```
TDAAtest %>% f
     filter(!is.na(State)) %>%
     group_by(State) %>% 
     mutate(n= n()) %>% 
     distinct(State, .keep_all=TRUE)
```

Answer (score 10):

To retain all columns, you can include `across()` as a `summarize` argument, as explained in the documentation for `dplyr::do()`.

```
by_cyl <- head(mtcars) %>%
  group_by(cyl)
by_cyl %>%
  summarise(m_mpg = mean(mpg), across())

    cyl m_mpg   mpg  disp    hp  drat    wt  qsec    vs    am  gear  carb
  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1     4  22.8  22.8   108    93  3.85  2.32  18.6     1     1     4     1
2     6  20.4  21     160   110  3.9   2.62  16.5     0     1     4     4
3     6  20.4  21     160   110  3.9   2.88  17.0     0     1     4     4
4     6  20.4  21.4   258   110  3.08  3.22  19.4     1     0     3     1
5     6  20.4  18.1   225   105  2.76  3.46  20.2     1     0     3     1
6     8  18.7  18.7   360   175  3.15  3.44  17.0     0     0     3     2
```

To retain only a subset of unaltered columns, you can select them within `across` using `tidyselect` semantics.

Comment: What would be the specific syntax to retain only one column? by_cyl %>%
  summarise(m_mpg = mean(mpg), across(select(hp)) doesn't work

Comment: You don't need `select()` within `across` (`select` already has tidyselect semantics); `by_cyl %>% summarise(m_mpg = mean(mpg), across(hp))` should work

Answer (score 6):

I believe there are more accurate answers than the accepted answer specially when you don't have unique data for other columns in each group (e.g. max or min or top n items based on one particular column
).

Although the accepted answer works for this question, for instance, you would like to find the county with the max population for each state. (You need to have `county` and `population` columns).

We have the following options:

**1. dplyr version**

From [this link](https://community.rstudio.com/t/summarise-max-but-keep-all-columns/52449/4), you have three extra operations (`mutate`, `ungroup` and `filter`) to achieve that:

```
TDAAtest %>% 
     filter(!is.na(State)) %>%
     group_by(State) %>% 
     mutate(maxPopulation = max(Population)) %>% 
     ungroup() %>%
     filter(maxPopulation == Population)
```

**2. Function version**

This one gives you as much flexibility as you want and you can apply any kind of operation to each group:

```
maxFUN = function(x) {
  # order population in a descending order
  x = x[with(x, order(-Population)), ]
  x[1, ]
}

TDAAtest %>% 
     filter(!is.na(State)) %>%
     group_by(State) %>%
     do(maxFUN(.))
```

This one is highly recommended for more complex operations. For instance, you can return top n (`topN`) counties per state by having `x[1:topN]` for the returned dataframe in `maxFUN`.