# How to use summarise() and keep other columns in R?

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse, data-cleaning, data-wrangling

This isn't a duplicate of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39092110/r-dplyr-summarize-and-retain-other-columns), since I'm asking to retain a column with a condition. I'd like to group a value in a column `x` and sum the corresponding values in another column `z`. I have the following data:

```
df <- data.frame(x = c("a", "a"),
                 y = c("a", "b"),
                 z = c(4, 5))

x y z
a a 4
a b 5
```

I can use `summarise()` from `dplyr` to do this, like so:

```
df %>% 
  group_by(x) %>% 
  summarise(z = sum(z))

x z
a 9
```

But I want to keep the column `y` when `x = y`, so the final output should look like this:

```
x y z
a a 9
```

How do I do this?

Comment: When x = y, the output is a, a, 4

Comment: No. Perhaps reading the question might help: I want to group by `x` to obtain a sum of `z` and retain `y` when `x=y`. Therefore, the grouping takes place for the value `a` in `x`, and generates the sum `4 + 5` in `z`.

Comment: The problem is that `mutate()` allows to keep the other column, but doesn't group by `x` since the values in `y` are not the same. So nothing happens.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

##### The short answer

What you want is this:

```
df %>% 
  mutate(z = sum(z),.by = x) %>%
  filter(x == y)
  x y z
1 a a 9
```

##### The long answer

The way `summarise` works is:

> `summarise()` creates a new data frame. It returns one row for each combination of grouping variables; if there are no grouping variables, the output will have a single row summarising all observations in the input. It will contain one column for each grouping variable and one column for each of the summary statistics that you have specified.

From what I understand, you're asking to group by `x`, use `summarise` to find the sum of `z`, but retain the value of `y` when `x == y`.

The issue with that, as you can see from the description, is that you're wanting to find the sum of `z` while grouping only by `x`, but then keep the value of `y` when `x == y` somehow. You can either group by x **and** y, and get the sum of `z` using `summarise`, or you can get the sum of `z` grouped by just `x` using `summarise`, but you can't have both.

It sounds like what you want is to use `mutate`. That way, you can replace *every* value of `z` with the sum of `z` grouped by `x`, and then filter the rows to the one where `x == y`.